# why getting 500 error for single sign on logout

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to test in Bluemix the Single Sign On Logout and I'm receiving a http status 500 when going to the `logout_success.html` page.

**I created-**

```
app.get('/logout', function(req,res){   

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout/logout_success.html');

    });
```

It looks like the logout returned a status of 302 and in the response header Location it has what's in the `res.redirect`.

Then when it tries to process the redirect command that comes back with `http 500 status error`. Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your logout code should be

```
app.get('/logout', function(req,res){   

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout');

});
```

After the redirect to /idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout, the logout_success.html page should be displayed without having to send the browser directly to it.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I'm still getting the http status 500 error.  The GET logout came back with a status 302 and here's the Location- :"https://61sso-01lnubchl2-ct20.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout"

Comment: I tried your logout code in my app and it's working for me. And the url you have there works fine (as long as you remove the quote when you click it, but I think that's just the way stack overflow displaying the link)

Are there any messages sent back with the 500 error?

Comment: All I get is Status Code: 500 Error with Request headers: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 61sso-01lnubchl2-ct20.iam.ibmcloud.com
Origin: https://testlogout.mybluemix.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0    and Response headers:   Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL

Comment: if I just click on that link in the location it works for me too

Comment: I just saw this-Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://61sso-01lnubchl2-ct20.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: I reran with this @ricampbe  -    req.logout();
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://testlogout.mybluemix.net');
res.redirect('https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout');   but still not working

Comment: I get the same error when testing with google chrome or firefox.  I am setting it I think, unless this is wrong-   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://testlogout.mybluemix.net');

Comment: Ah ok, you need to set your app as an allowed origin in your SSO service settings. If you go to the settings, you should find a section called Origins. Add the URL for your app. You'll need to include the protocol, hostname, and possibly the port (I think you need this even if you're using 80 or 443, but not 100%). You can find more info on the Origins here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/con_servicesettings.html#con_servicesettings

Comment: I added in Origins my app's url, with ports and without, separated by commas. I am not setting the Logout setting, leaving that blank. In my app.js I have this-   req.logout();
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://ltdrsso.mybluemix.net:443');
 res.redirect('https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout');      and I am now getting HTTP 404 not found along with the Cross-Origin Request Blocked error